# A set theory proving question with symmetrical difference.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have this task and i'm quite stuck.

Prove that if $A \cap B = \emptyset $, $(A \Delta C) \cup (B \Delta C) = A \cup B \cup C$.

Currently i am  trying to show that $(A \Delta C) \cup (B \Delta C) \subseteq A \cup B \cup C$  by breaking down the left hand side.
iv'e came to the conclusion that for a given $x$,
$[x \in (A \cup C) \land x \notin (A \cap C)] \lor [x \in (B \cup C) \land x \notin (B \cap C)] $
all using logical bi-conditionals and the definitions. I know i need to somehow show the $x$ is part of the right hand side and currently stuck. Afterwards of course i'll need to show the opposite way as it's part of $=$ definition. I'm sorry if the questions doesn't follow the site guidelines / i offended someone. this is my first time here and this is my first question.
Thank you!

Comment: Questions of the form "here's a homework problem, solve it!" are often not so well received here. However, people will be much happier (and better able) to help if you add context to the question. For example: What have you tried so far? What are some theorems or facts that you think might be useful here?

Comment: Nothing to do with Group theory. Why do you tag it group theory, and put "group theory" in the subject line? (Yes, the symmetric difference is a group operation in a certain set, but this quesiton is *not* about that group). And why is this tagged "solution-verification" when not only did you not provide a solution, you provide **nothing** but the statement problem for us to do it for you?

Comment: I am so sorry. As English is not my mothers tongue ironically we call set theory "Group theory" in my county, learned a new thing. I've elaborated on my question and where iv'e gone with my solution. Again terribly sorry.

Comment: The question as edited is fine.  The containment you're working on strikes me as the easier part of the proof, and doesn't seem to need the additional condition that $A \cap B = \varnothing$.  It seems intuitively obvious that if $x$ is an element of the left-hand side, it must also be an element of $A, B$, or $C$, which is all you're trying to prove with this containment.  Can you formalize this intuition?

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
I do actually have a big of problem formalizing it. In order to show that x is an element of A∪B∪C i need to show that $x \in A \lor x \in B \lor x \in C$. I still have hard time to grasp how it is being given for the left hand side...
About $A \cap B = \emptyset$ i guess it will come handy in the second part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show LHS $\subseteq$ RHS, you could show:

1. If $x \in A \Delta C$, then $x$ is contained in at least one of $A, B, C$.
2. If $x \in B \Delta C$, then $x$ is contained in at least one of $A, B, C$.

(Do you see why those statements would prove this direction?)

To show RHS $\subseteq$ LHS, you should show:

1. If $x \in A$, then $x$ is contained in at least one of $A \Delta C$ or $B \Delta C$.
2. If $x \in B$, then $x$ is contained in at least one of $A \Delta C$ or $B \Delta C$.
3. If $x \in C$, then $x$ is contained in at least one of $A \Delta C$ or $B \Delta C$.

(Again, do you see why those statements together would imply the result you want?)

---

To prove these individual statements, the key idea is to break into cases based on whether $x$ is in $A$, $B$, and/or $C$. I'll show how to prove one of the statements as an example, and then you could try to prove the others yourself. I'll prove: *If $x \in A$, then $x$ is contained in at least one of $A \Delta C$ or $B \Delta C$.*

Well, $x \in A$, so we know $x \not \in B$ by the initial assumption $A \cap B = \emptyset$. If $x \in C$ then we have $x \in (B \cup C)$ and $x \not \in (B \cap C)$, which means $x \in (B \Delta C)$ using the definition you gave. On the other hand, if $x \not \in C$ then we have $x \in (A \cup C$ and $x \not \in (A \cap C)$, which means $x \in (A \Delta C)$. So either way, we get $x \in (A \Delta C) \cup (B \Delta C)$.

Comment: This is amazing. Thank you very much for the guidance, i think i can get it up from here. Sorry again for the initial question, learning as i progress :)

Comment: It's no problem at all. Totally normal to not know the guidelines at first. Thanks for editing the question to improve it!

Comment: One more question about the answer you proposed - 
Isn't it suffice to only proof one of those 3 within the $RHS \subseteq LHS$  is Truth and than with the definition of union (Which is implemented with "or") that the statement  $(A \Delta C) \cup (B \Delta C)$ is valid as well?
Or maybe it isn't a valid proof at all? Thanks!

Comment: To show $A \cup B \cup C \subseteq$ LHS, you need to show $A \subseteq LHS$ and $B \subseteq LHS$ and $C \subseteq LHS$.

With your version, you'd just be showing $A \subseteq LHS$ and calling it a day, but that's not sufficient.

Comment: If you're having trouble seeing why, you could try two approaches. First, carefully write out what it means for $A \cup B \cup C \subseteq X$ vs $A \subseteq X$ vs $B \subseteq X$ vs $C \subseteq X$ and see if you can understand how the implications work that way. Second, it might help to try to "think about it intuitively", like draw some Venn diagrams or just think about what the different inclusions would mean. I know it's hard to develop intuition about this stuff at first, but you eventually want to reach a state where you can figure out what's true without needing all the formalism.

Comment: I should have added in my comment that i'm plainly asking for clarification of the proofing technique. I have successfully proved the task using your guidance and showed all 3 of them are True. Just thought maybe only one is enough but i see now that it isn't correct way of proving "If $A \lor B \lor C than .... $" style of statements.